# Android Tcpclient for Receiving a document and printing data

Tags: java, android, tcpclient, tcpserver

I have button for printing data for this I've set listener method. Here it send Msg to server for pdf document using `HomeFragment.java` and store in a directory using `TcpClient.java`

```
HomeFragment.java

 holder.btnPrint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
                        if (socketTask != null) {
                            new Thread(() -> {
                                if (socketTask.getTcpClient() != null) {
                                    if (socketTask.getTcpClient().getSocket() != null) {
                                        if (socketTask.getTcpClient().getSocket().isConnected()) {
                                            socketTask.getTcpClient().sendMessage("TAGPRINT:" + holder.chipTagNo.getText().toString() + ":" + edt_gst.getText().toString()
                                                    + ":" + holder.txt_making_charge.getText().toString() + ":" + holder.txt_rate.getText().toString() + ":" + edt_cust_name.getText().toString()
                                                    + ":" + edt_customer_name.getText().toString() + ":" + holder.txt_ghat_weight.getText().toString());
                                            TCPClient.isPDF = true;
                                        } else {
                                            setStatus(SocketStatus.DISCONNECTED);
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        setStatus(SocketStatus.DISCONNECTED);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    setStatus(SocketStatus.DISCONNECTED);
                                }
                            }).start();
                        }

                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(),
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
                        } else {
                            startPrintJob();
                        }
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check wifi connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


// For printing a document 

   private void startPrintJob() {
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) requireContext().getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
        String jobName = "MyPrintJob";

        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = new PrintDocumentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes,
                                 CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback,
                                 Bundle extras) {
                if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                    callback.onLayoutCancelled();
                    return;
                }

                PrintDocumentInfo info = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("print_output.pdf")
                        .setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
                        .setPageCount(PrintDocumentInfo.PAGE_COUNT_UNKNOWN)
                        .build();

                callback.onLayoutFinished(info, true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination,
                                CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback) {
                FileInputStream input = null;
                FileOutputStream output = null;
                try {
                    File downloadsFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                    File fileToPrint = new File(downloadsFolder, "SamplePDF.pdf");

                    input = new FileInputStream(fileToPrint);
                    output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());

                    byte[] buf = new byte[16384];
                    int size;
                    while ((size = input.read(buf)) >= 0 && !cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                        output.write(buf, 0, size);
                    }

                    if (!cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                        callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});
                    } else {
                        callback.onWriteCancelled();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    callback.onWriteFailed(e.toString());
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (input != null) {
                            input.close();
                        }
                        if (output != null) {
                            output.close();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, null);
        if (printJob != null) {
            if (printJob.isCompleted()) {
            } else if (printJob.isFailed()) {
            }
        }
    }
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startPrintJob();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here i set `TCPClient.isPDF = true;` As a purpose that sending a msg to server `TAGPRINT` and ask server for send a pdf file...

```
TcpClient.java

 if (isPDF) {
                            isUTF = true;
                            isPDF = false;
                            try {
                                byte[] encoded = (byte[]) in.readObject();
                                pdfdecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
                                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),               "demo.pdf");
                                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                fos.write(TCPClient.pdfdecoded);
                                fos.flush();
                                fos.close();

                      
                                Log.d("pdfB", "run: ");

                            } catch (Exception exception) {
                                exception.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

I want to achieve that Server first check if pdf is stored correctly inside directory.. If it stored correctly then after `fos.close() of TcpClient`  `print method of HomeFragment`should execute for printing data...